# Interleaved Sortkeys Not Supported Yet - Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

So, I'm trying to create a Redshift table with an interleaved sort key, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_app_data
(
    "date" date,
    identifier_id int,
    app_id int,
    iface_name char(1),
    roaming boolean,
    tx_bytes bigint,
    rx_bytes bigint
)
diststyle key
distkey (app_id)
interleaved sortkey ("date", app_id);
```

The documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Sorting_data.html) makes it very clear that this is possible.

However, when I execute the above query, I get this error: `ERROR: INTERLEAVED SORTKEY is not supported yet`. The Google hasn't been much help.

Any suggestions on what's going on?

Comment: Based on an AWS blog post, it looks like they only released the feature 10 days ago. So, I guess it's possible that they have announced it, but not pushed it out to production yet? Seems kind of fishy...

Comment: In which AWS region do you run?

Comment: We're in Northern Virginia.

Comment: Working for me - but note - if you use a distribution style of all with interleaved sort key the vacuum command fails... apparently it should be fixed in a future maintenance update - didn't stop our site going down in the meantime though...